# How DB auto connect in two different versions of sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Express Edition and I restored one DB in that. After that I have uninstalled SQL Server Management studio 2014 Express Edition and I have Installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Enterprise Edition.

After installation, the DB which I have created in the Express edition is automatically connected with the Enterprise edition on the first run itself.

How does this happen and why?

Comment: Do you registered your server on the 2014 Express Edition ? Maybe SSMS keep the registered servers somewhere and that's why you have the auto connection on the Enterprise Edition

Comment: ok got it thanks. and what is SSMS.

Comment: It is SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps

Comment: If the answer fits your need, can you validate it so your question is closed ? Tks, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've registered your DB in the SSMS 2014 Express Studio, SSMS keep track of those registration. You may have register the name of the server on the file host in your machine. In this way, SSMS kept track of your server even if it's been reinstall.

You can find the list of register server here :

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml

In this way, it keep the list of the register server.